# Como chama a função cast() do banco de dados no método ORDER de um banco de dados numa expressão LINQ em C# C#?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, asp-net-core

Eu tenho um campo que armazena `DATETIME` no meu banco de dados. Porém eu preciso ignorar a hora desse campo quando eu for ordenar por ele.
O seguinte código faz a minha busca:

```
public virtual async Task<(List<TModel>, int)> FindAsync(IQueryable<TModel> query, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 20, string[] sortExpression = null, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> includes = null)
    {
        query = Includes(includes, query);
        query = SetFilterAll(query);

        var count = await query.CountAsync();
        query = Sort(sortExpression, query);
        query = Pagination(pageNumber, pageSize, query);
        return (await query.ToListAsync(), count);
    }
```

Gostaria de mandar no parâmetro `sortExpresion` algo como, 
`CAST(meu_campo_date AS DATE)`
Para que no final executasse o um SQL semelhante a esse:

```
SELECT * FROM MinhaTabela ORDER BY CAST(meu_campo_date AS DATE) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade `Datetime.Date`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Isto irá imprimir a data e hora: {dateTime}");
        Console.WriteLine("Isto irá imprimir apenas a data: {dateTime.Date}");
    }
}
```

Veja esse exemplo no .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jixgMY

Comment: Nesse caso não me atende, Keven.
Eu preciso que na há hora que o ORDER BY for execultar a minha consulta SQL usar apenas a data. O ponto crítico é que preciso fazer isso pelo entityframework mandando pelo método de extensão da interface IQueryable.

Comment: Como você não colocou o método `sort` eu não tenho como saber exatamente como a ordenação foi implementada, mas seria algo do tipo `query.OrderBy(x => x.SuaPropriedadeData.Date)`. Desta forma o próprio EntityFramework montaria a ordenação da consulta.